# Shopify API call limit for private apps

Tags: shopify

We are developing a private app for use with our Shopify store. To ensure we don't cross the API limits, we've implemented a basic configurable delay per API call.

We started with the documented API limit of 500 calls every 5 minutes, which mapped to a delay of 600ms per call. However, after 50 calls the server doesn't respond to the HTTP GET.

Even after we increased the delay to 1200ms per API call, it still fails after 50 calls.

We are using the Shopify4J on a store that is in a trial period (myfirststore-3).

I've looked at the wiki, api docs, forums and SO - but there is no mention of any other limit except the official 500/5min limit.

Are we running into a different call limit for private apps or trial stores ?

Comment: What kind of response are you getting back?

Comment: The response to the 50th GET is \n0\n  
See trace from HTTPClient logs....
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> GET /admin/products/count.json HTTP/1.1
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: myfirststore-3.myshopify.com
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Cookie: _secure_session_id=02cc7a4d48dc879ecd7b1a692042b29e
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpResponseParser - Garbage in response:

Comment: Based on this and our logs it doesn't look like the request is even getting to us. Can you verify that the request is actually being sent across the network?

Comment: John ... I ran a proxy server on my machine and spoofed the hostnames so that our code connects to it. From the logs of the proxy I can see that the GET request is happening. Since the problem is in the client code (see answer below), we still need to figure out where we are running into a problem. Thanks for your time looking at the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is in the java client implementation itself. We figured this out by adding all initializations inside our loop.

After making that change, we were able to make up to 500 API call per 5 minutes as documented.

We had added the apache httpclient library to the Shopify4J package to make it work on our backend servers, and it probably needs some tweaking. Ofcourse this is not a long term solution to our problem but it does answer this question.

Once we figure out the problem in our code, will post a comment here.